# The length of an arc through parametric equations

Tags: integration, parametric, arc-length

Prove that the length l of an arc given by the parametric equations $x = \theta$  and $y = (\sec\theta)^2 $  from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ is given by $l = \ln(1 + \sqrt{2})$.

I have used the formula

$l = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{d\theta})^2 + (\frac{dy}{d\theta})^2} d\theta$

So I  solved the equation above until

$l = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \sqrt{1 + (2\tan\theta\sec^2\theta)^2} d\theta$

Is the integral above possible to solve?

Comment: Looks like you set up the integral correctly. Not sure how to solve it though. Double-check the problem statement.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha cannot solve this integral and only gives the numerical value $s=1.36751$. I have found the same value using a different method of integration (in the complex plane, starting with $z=\theta+i*\sec^2\theta$ and $s=\int|\dot z|d\theta$).

Comment: Well @Cye Waldman $l = \ln(1+\sqrt{2}) \not = 1.36751$ could it really be that the proof does not equate.

Comment: @RobertMdee It certainly seems so, but more to the point was that WA could not integrate it. It would be interesting if someone could try that integral on Maple. \